# How to interpret the Oracle Java API Documentation

Tags: java, api

I somehow find it hard to understand the Java API Documentation in Oracle's website. I've printed a lot of pages already from selected classes that for me are basic ones but I only know a number of methods to encode or type properly. Like for example, in the Applet class documentation, you will find the Method Summary that summarizes all the methods belonging to that class. My question is, how will you encode or type the methods of various Java classes? For example, for the Applet class, we all know that public void init() method must be created as an entire method with, of course, a method body within parentheses; I also know the parseInt, parseDouble, parseFloat, etc . Did you get what I'm trying to say here? Okay, let me give you one more example. Let's take a look into the Method Summary of the String class of the Java.lang package. So how will you write the methods:

```
char charAt(int index)
int codePointAt(int index)
int codePointBefore(int index)
int codePointCount(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
int compareTo(String anotherString)
String concat(String str)
boolean contains(CharSequence s)
boolean contentEquals(CharSequence cs)
static String copyValueOf(char[] data, int offset, int count)
boolean endsWith(String suffix)
boolean equals(Object anObject)
boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString)
static String format(Locale l, String format, Object... args)
static String format(String format, Object... args)
byte[] getBytes()
byte{} getBytes(Charset charset)
byte[] getBytes(String charsetName)
void getChars(int srcBegin, int srcEnd, char[] dst, int dstBegin)
int hashCode()
int indexOf(int ch)
int indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)
int indexOf(String str)
int indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)
boolean isEmpty()
int lastIndexOf(int ch)
int lastIndexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)
int lastIndexOf(String str)
int lastIndexOf(String str, fromIndex)
int length()
boolean matches(String regex)
int offsetByCodePoints(int index, int codePointOffset)
boolean regionMatches(boolean ignoreCase, int toffset, String other, int ooffset, int len)
boolean regionMatches(int toffset, String other, int ooffset, int len)
String replace(char oldchar, char newChar)
String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
String replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)
String[] split(String regex)
String[] split(String regex, int limit)
boolean startsWith(String prefix)
boolean startsWith(String prefix, int toffset)
CharSequence subSequence(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
String substring(int beginIndex)
String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
char[] toCharArray()
String toLowerCase()
String toLowerCase(Locale locale)
String toString()
String toUpperCase()
String toUpperCase(Locale locale)
String trim()
static String valueOf(boolean b)
static String valueOf(char c)
static String valueOf(char[] data)
static String valueOf(char[] data, int offset, int count)
static String valueOf(double d)
static String valueOf(float f)
static String valueOf(int i)
static String valueOf(long l)
static String valueOf(Object obj)
```

Like for example, do I write int length() as, declared String thisIsString = "Ryan", "thisIsString.length()" or "String.length()" or do I need to write an entire method body with parentheses? I've already encountered several methods already of different classes and somehow know now how to properly use them. I'm trying to fully comprehend how to write methods of various classes properly by trying them one by one but I end up in an error with some of them. Please shed light on me great, magnificent Java programmers of stackoverflow.

Comment: If you see `static`, then the method can be used with the form `<classname>.<staticmethod>`. Otherwise, the method is an *instance* method, and can only be called from an instance of that class `<objectofclass>.<instancemethod>`. Well, in Java, you can call static method from an instance of the class, but it is discouraged, since it makes the code harder to read.

Comment: Why don't you start with a Java tutorial?

Comment: You seem to mixing up implementing a method with invoking it...  When you write a method body of Applet.init you're implementing it and creating your own applet.  When you invoke String.length you're using somebody else's implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to your last example:

```
String thisIsString = "Ryan"
```

you would use:

```
thisIsString.length()
```

As you can see, the `.length()` method is of type int. Therefore, your answer will be of type int. If the method is of type boolean for example, your result will yield a true or false value.

Now, if we look at `String replace(char oldchar, char newChar)`:

This method looks at a String and returns a String. Inside the parenthesis are the parameters (what the function takes in). So if you have `String x = "pool"`, you can do, `x.replace("p","c")` which will yield the word "cool". The `replace()` method as you can see takes in characters as its arguments.

Hope that helps clear things a little.